# Github pages not accessible after deleting CNAME

Tags: github, github-pages

I had a working github pages before at http://igghub.github.io/

I was trying to figure out how to add custom domain. I followed [this guide from gh-pages](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-or-removing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/) on how to add custom domain. On my repo's `Custom Domain` setting, I nonchalantly added `iggy.io` and saved it. Silly me, I did not create DNS (I didn't know what it was until now).

Naturally, when I typed either `igghub.github.io` or `iggy.io`, it didn't work. So I deleted the `iggy.io` custom domain and saved it.

[image: github setting]

However, I am still unable to access github pages even after I cleared out custom domain! Everytime I try going to [igghub.github.io](https://igghub.github.io/) it *still* redirects to [iggy.io](http://iggy.io).

The last 2 commits showed that CNAME was finally deleted.

[image: CNAME]

Why can't I access my old github-pages and why does github-pages still redirect me to the deleted custom domain?

Comment: works for me. Try clearing your browser cache, may have a temp or perm HTTP redirect stored in there

Comment: Oh shoot. Thanks!! I didn't think about clearing cache browser until you mentioned it. Thank you so very much @StephenG!!! It works again now :)

Comment: @StephenG Care to post that as an answer so that this issue can be marked answered?

Comment: @KeithBennett done

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your browser cache, may have a temp or perm HTTP redirect stored in there